# Mean SQL in Rails 4 without SQL using joins and where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, model

A location belongs to one or more entities. An entity can have one or more locations.

I try to get all other locations that have the same entity like the current location.

I have the following model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_assignments
  has_many :entities, :through => :location_assignments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location_assignments
end

class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :location_assignments
   has_many :locations, through: :location_assignments
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :location_assignments
end
```

This is in SQL what I want

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.* FROM locations l, location_assignments la, entities e
WHERE l.id = la.location_id
AND la.entity_id = e.id
AND e.id in ( SELECT ee.id from entities ee, location_assignments laa
WHERE ee.id = laa.entity_id
AND laa.location_id = 1)
```

But I don't want to use SQL.
This is what I tried with Rails

```
Location.joins(:entities => :locations).where(:locations => {:id => location.id})
```

It gives me several times the current location. The amount of rows is the same like the SQL (without distinct to get the current location only ones).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to mimic your SQL which uses a subquery and just use standard ActiveRecord querying without dropping down to AREL.  Let's start with the subquery:

```
Entity.joins(:location_assignments).where(:location_assignments => {:location_id => location.id})
```

This returns a relation which contains all the entities which have the location represented by location.id associated with them, just like your SQL subquery.

Then the main query, with the subquery as xxxxx for now for readability:

```
Location.joins(:entities).where(:entities => {:id => xxxxx})
```

This is the equivalent of your main query.  Plugging in the subquery which returns what is basically an array of entities (ok, a relation, but same effect in this case) prompts ActiveRecord to turn the WHERE condition into an IN rather than just an =.  ActiveRecord is also smart enough to use the id of each entity.  So, plug in the subquery:

```
Location.joins(:entities).where(:entities => {:id => Entity.joins(:location_assignments).where(:location_assignments => {:location_id => location.id})})
```

Note that like your query, this returns the original location you started with, as well as all the others which share the same entities.

I think this should be equivalent to your SQL, but see how it goes on your data!

If you want to make the query more efficient using a self join (which means that instead of having 2 joins and a subquery with another join, you can just have 2 joins) but without using SQL fragment strings, I think you might need to drop down to AREL something like this:

```
l = Arel::Table.new(:locations)
la = Arel::Table.new(:location_assignments)
starting_location_la = la.alias
l_joined_la = l.join(la).on(l[:id].eq(la[:location_id]))
filtered_and_projected = l_joined_la.join(starting_location_la).on(starting_location_la[:entity_id].eq(la[:entity_id])).where(starting_location_la[:location_id].eq(location.id)).project(location[Arel.star])
Location.find_by_sql(filtered_and_projected)
```

This just joins all locations to their location assignments and then joins again with the location assignments using entity id, but only with those belonging to your starting location object so it acts like a filter.  This gives me the same results as the previous approach using standard ActiveRecord querying, but again, see how it goes on your data!